# The group of buttons goes beyond the block border. How to do it right?

Tags: html, css, button, bootstrap-modal, responsive

The group of buttons goes beyond the block border. How to do it right? And make responsive

```css
  .btn-group button {
    padding: 10px 24px; 
    cursor: pointer; 
    float: left; }
```

```html
<div class="col-lg-3 col-4">
            <div class="container">    
            <div class="button_section btn-group">
                <button class="btn section1_button button_twitter">
                    <img src="{{asset('images/haitacchienchien/events/header/header_twitter.png')}}" alt="">
                </button>
                <button class="btn section1_button button_facebook">
                    <img  src="{{asset('images/haitacchienchien/events/header/header_facebook.png')}}" alt="">
                </button>
                <button class="btn section1_button button_language">
                    <img  src="{{asset('images/haitacchienchien/events/header/header_language.png')}}" alt="">
                </button>
            </div>
            </div> 
        </div>
```

Comment: What **exactly** do you mean by "make it responsive"?

Comment: I've converted your posted code to an interactive snippet and it looks fine to me.

Comment: adaptive to mobile. But anyway I want all buttons on 1 line. Now it look ok. But button very big. If I make img{width:100%;} it make group button very small. If I want change size buttons - it is does not work.

Comment: Don't use `float: left;`, use `.btn-group { display: flex; }` instead. `float` should generally be   avoided except for text-wrapping scenarios.

Comment: I try understand where I mistake. Want btn-group has size container. And for responsive button will always move together with  them block. I think my problem anywhere inside HTML.